# How can I create a Lazy C++ template class that handles types with no default constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, lazy-evaluation, copy-constructor

***Deleting this question in favor the following; an answer to which now handles classes with no default constructor:***

[How to abstract lazy initialization in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642824/how-do-i-do-lazy-initialization-or-lazy-instantiation-in-c/17642967#17642967)

In a nutshell, the code uses placement new/delete.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax for details...

Comment: Why do you put the value in an union with a char ?

Comment: Without variadic templates it'll be really difficult to provide a truly generic solution. What if your target can only be initialized with 21 arguments?

Comment: @Synxis - was trying to find a way to construct this class with an uninitialized T, because T can be expensive to construct.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - That's what "bind" is for ;-)

Comment: @Synxis - Removed the union, since it doesn't do what I want...

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`boost::optional<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html) instead of pair of your members `m_bInitialized` and `m_value`. Probably you could just use [`boost::optional<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html) instead of your `template class Lazy`...

If you really want to make it in your own way - then **steal** some implementation details from  [`boost::optional<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html).

One hint is that this boost class uses [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new):

```
class Lazy {
public:
   bool is_init() const { return m_memberPtr != nullptr; }
   T& force() 
   { 
      if (!is_init()) 
        m_memberPtr = new (m_memberMemory) T(m_initializer());
      return *m_memberPtr;
   }
private:
  T* m_memberPtr;
  alignas(T) char m_memberMemory[sizeof(T)]; // s
};
```

Comment: Rather than use boost::optional, I think using a shared_ptr in the target datatype will give what I want with minimal fuss.

Comment: I get it now, but boost::optional only satisfies explicit lazy instantiation via assignment; it doesn't handle implicit lazy instantiation via callback and explicit instantiation via passing as a pointer to a getter function, such as with many Win32 API's.  I am/was looking for a single class to do all 3.

Comment: @JamesHugard See my update. As I said, you can steal some implementation details from `boost::optional` - like this placement new trick. In this way you have memory in your class for the object, you can pass it to some "C" API to initialize it in other way.

Comment: as I said, I'm going to delete this question and ask in a simpler, more direct fashion.  Also, I created a new question to discuss lazy initialization in C++, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642824/how-do-i-do-lazy-initialization-or-lazy-instantiation-in-c/17642967#17642967